How to prevent fire spread exceeding maximal firefighting capacity in Emergency?
In some extreme shifts the condition heat or wind can cause a fire to spread from one building to the next (and back after extinction) faster than 10 firefighters (2 in each of 5 slots) can extinguish, i.e. if I abandon every other emergency, I cannot contain the fire and all other emergencies cause the chaos to rise to +1500 quickly.
What's the correct procedure? Extinguish as many fires as possible in parallel? One after the other with maximal force? Choose other abilities (I usually use extended capabilities of firefighter)? Give up the fire emergency and focus on others?
Or maybe this is a known issue of unbalanced impact of extreme conditions or just an animation to spend coins?
